# Typescript generics constraint in Vue components props

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
type Header<TForm=Record<string,any>,TInfo=TForm> = {
  title:string;
  key:keyof TForm;
}

type ResInfo = {
  name:string;
  age:number;
}

const headers:Header<ResInfo>[] = [
  {title:'Name',key:'name'},
  {title:'Age',key:'age'}
]

let headerProps:Header<Record<string,any>>[] = [];

headerProps = headers;
```

This code will report an error:

`The type "Record<string, any>" is missing the following attributes of the type "ResInfo" : name, age`.

I want to set the type of `headerProps` first, because it is the type of props for a vue component like:

```
const props = defineProps<{
  headerProps:Header<Record<string,any>>[]
}>();
```

However, when using this component, passing `headers` to `props.headerProps` prompts a type error.

Is there any way to fulfill my needs? like change the type of Header or Vue components props type?